# IDX10108: The address specified is not valid as per HTTPS scheme

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I hope someone can help me with solving my problem. I know similar questions have been posted before, and I looked thru them all.  None of the solutions worked for me thus far.

I'm getting the following error when my client is trying to connect to IdentityServer4:

```
System.ArgumentException: IDX10108: The address specified is not valid as per HTTPS scheme. Please specify an https address for security reasons. If you want to test with http address, set the RequireHttps property  on IDocumentRetriever to false.
```

Parameter name: http://subdomain.domain.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.d__24.MoveNext()

Everything worked fine locally, when run from VS 2017. When I tried to deploy to staging environment and host website in IIS (7.5) I started getting this error.

My staging setup:
IdentityServer4 running on top of ASP.net core 2.0 as it's own instance.
My client running on top of ASP.net core 2.0 as it's own instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is giving on IIS because HTTPS requires SSL and it is not configured correctly.
Check URL configuration and HTTPS binding with SSL.

Comment: I checked everything you suggested everything is setup correctly. Still getting same error.

Comment: @IgorRisis did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you have found the solution by now, but I ran into same error today and saw this post. So adding what I found and maybe someone else would get benefit from it.

For me, the Authority URL (OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.Authority) that I was forming from config values was not correct and causing this error, fixing that fixed my this error.